# Como obtener el termino independiente de una ecuacion en python?

Tags: python, sympy

Teniendo una ecuacion

```
from sympy import symbols
x,y=symbols('x,y)

eq=5*x-3*y+7

a=e.coeff(x)
```

Sé que por medio del método coeff se pueden hallar los coeficientes de cada variable ¿hay alguna forma en la que pueda obtener el termino independiente de la ecuacion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La función `coeff()` admite un segundo parámetro para especificar el grado del término. Así si pones `eq.coeff(x, 0)` te daría el término independiente con respecto a x.

Sin embargo el concepto "término independiente" es relativo a una variable. El término independiente respecto a la variable "x", y serían en realidad todos los términos que no dependan de x. Pero tu ecuación tiene dos variables. Si nos preguntamos por el término independiente respecto a x, resulta que tenemos dos: `-3y` y `7` pues ninguno de ellos depende de x.

```
from sympy import symbols
x,y=symbols('x,y')

eq=5*x-3*y+7
print(eq.coeff(x, 0))
```

Imprime `7-3*y`

Por tanto no parece que `coeff()` sea la mejor vía.

Creo que puede ser mucho más simple el uso de `eq.as_ordered_terms()` que te devuelve una lista de términos, por orden decreciente de grado. El último elemento de esa lista sería el término de menor grado:

```
indep = eq.as_ordered_terms()[-1]
print(indep)
```

Esto imprime 7.

El único problema es el caso en que la ecuación no tenga término indpendiente. En ese caso este código te daría el término de menor grado de todas formas, pero no sería el término independiente que buscabas. Una solución a este problema es verificar si el término que has obtenido es un número. Si lo es, es el término independiente buscado. Si no lo es, el término independiente sería 0.

En base a esto podemos escribir la siguiente función:

```
def obtener_termino_independiente(eq):
  indep = eq.as_ordered_terms()[-1]
  if indep.is_number():
    return indep
  else:
    return 0
```